# Split a string within an array list each time a character is encountered

Tags: java, regex, arrays, string

I am trying to break a string down into an array list consisting of lines of text. A line is created either every 90 characters, or when a line break (\r) is encountered.

I am using this to break the string into an array every 90 characters (partionSize in the code):

```
    private static List<String> getParts(String string, int partitionSize) {
    List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
    int len = string.length();
    for (int i=0; i<len; i+=partitionSize)
    {
        parts.add(string.substring(i, Math.min(len, i + partitionSize)));
    }
    return parts;
    }
```

How can I modify this so that it checks for line breaks ("\r") and splits each time one is detected, plus splits every 90 characters?

__

UPDATE:

Using Regex solution provided below, like so:

```
String[] parts = string.split("(?<=\\G.{" + partitionSize + "})|\r|\n");
```

I input a string broken over multiple lines, for example:

```
 1. 
 2. 
 3. 
 4.
 5.
```

When I split it into array[] parts using the regex below, parts.length is 8, and printing each item in parts returns this:

```
line 0 is 1. 
line 1 is 
line 2 is 2. 
line 3 is 
line 4 is 3.
line 5 is 
line 6 is 4.
line 7 is 
line 8 is 5.
```

For this case, parts.length should be 5.

Comment: I don't think you would get that output for your string. Please check it again. It's giving me required output for that string.

Comment: If I do this, then it works: String[] parts = string.split("(?<=\\G.{" + partitionSize + "})|\r\n");  Am I missing something by having removed this bit from your answer |[\r\n]| ?

Comment: Line separator varies based on OS. On Unix it's `\n`, on windows it's `\r\n`, and on MAC it's `\r`.

Comment: Interesting. For a Java web application, where string is user-inputted text, would that be the OS of the user or the system the application runs on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split using the following regex:

```
String[] arr = str.split("(?<=\\G.{90})|[\r\n]|\r\n");
```

- `(?<=\\G.{90})` splits on empty string preceded by 90 characters, starting from the previous match. `\\G` anchor causes the regex to start matching from where the previous match ended. So first it matches `90` characters at the beginning, then it matches the next `90` characters, and so on.
- `[\r\n]` splits on either `\r` or `\n`.
- `\r\n` splits on `\r\n`, which is line separator on windows.

**Demo Code:**

```
String str = "abcdefghi\njkl\rmnopasdf";            
int maxCharacters = 5;

String[] arr = str.split("(?<=\\G.{" + maxCharacters + "})|[\r\n]|\r\n");       
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

**Output:**

```
[abcde, fghi, jkl, mnopa, sdf]
```

---

**References:**

- [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

  - [Continuing matches](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html)

Comment: Can I use a variable in that regex, ie instead of {90}, {MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINES} or so?

Comment: @Ali Yes you can. Just use string concatenation to build regex.

Comment: I get an odd result from this regex. If I loop through and print out each item in parts, I get an additional split for each line break. For example, if I input a string "1. 2. 3. 4. " with each on a separate line, the output shows item 1 = "1. " item 2 = "" item 3 = "2. " item 4 = "" and so on. Do you think this has to do with the format my string is going in as?

Comment: @Ali It's difficult to visualize your string in comments. Rather add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would call `string.split("\r")` to create an array of string split on a line-break. Then iterate through each one, and if it is over 90 characters long, split it at that point.

Comment: You'll have to dynamically make the array bigger at each split at 90 chars

Comment: Very true. The answers above involving a regex are a much better solution.